# How to block Nginx requests where http_referer matches requested URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to block a webcrawler that uses the requested page as the http_referer, and I can't figure out what variable to compare it to.

e.g.

```
location / {
  if ($the_variable_with_the_current_full_uri = $http_referer) {
    return 403;
  }
}
```

The variable has to match protocol, host, and URL, so that internal redirects from http to https don't get blocked.

So if someone requests "https://www.example.com/pages/1" with the $http_referer of "https://www.example.com/pages/1", it should be blocked.

As a secondary question, is it possible block requests on two conditions: where the above check matches, as well as matching a specific user agent string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full URL can be constructed by concatenating a number of variables together.

For example:

```
$scheme://$host$request_uri
```

The secondary condition could be handled using a `map` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map)).

For example:

```
map $http_user_agent $my_http_referer {
    default      "";
    blahblah     $http_referer;
}
server {
    ...
    if ($scheme://$host$request_uri = $my_http_referer) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent I'll give this a try. Interesting that there's no built-in variable that represents the full URL. I can't even find a list of available variables on the Nginx website. Also, gotta check if "blahblah" can be quotes and entered as is, or if I have to escape the string...

Comment: I find [this website](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) useful. See the "Alphabetical index of variables" part way down the page.

Comment: See the `map` documentation linked in my answer, but you will probably want to use a regular expression to match part of the string.